# Execution failed for task ':stripe_stripe-react-native:compileDebugKotlin'. after updating @stripe/stripe-react-native to 0.21.0

Tags: android, react-native, stripe-payments

Im getting the following error after running `yarn run android`:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':stripe_stripe-react-native:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details
```

i had to update @stripe/stripe-react-native because mi app was getting an error in the new xcode 14, my app is running well in ios, but in android im getting this error, please i need help...

i tried workarounds but didnt work

Comment: You would need to find the "real" compilation error it said "See log for more details", then create a Github issue in https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/issues and include your full log.